# Create a duplicate row in csv file to separate multiple values in a column (python)

Tags: python, csv, python-2.6

I am trying to build some code in Python to separate multiple values in a column into separate rows and aggregate the column for `Active-Ticket` based on the same day for the timestamp, is there any internal library can be used or do I need to install an external library?

My sample file is (for now, the Active-Tickets column is empty):

**Input.csv**

```
Timestamp,CaseID,Active-Tickets   
14FEB2017:10:55:23,K456 G578 T213,        
13FEB2017:10:56:12,F891 A63,
14FEB2017:11:59:14,T427 T31212 F900000,
15FEB2017:03:55:23,K456 G578 T213,        
14FEB2017:05:56:12,F891 A63,
```

What I am trying to achieve:

**Output.csv**

```
Timestamp,CaseID,Active-Tickets
14FEB2017:10:55:23,K456,8 (because there are 8 cases happened on the same day)
14FEB2017:10:55:23,G578,8
14FEB2017:10:55:23,T213,8        
13FEB2017:10:56:12,F891,2 (because there are 2 cases happened on the same day)
13FEB2017:10:56:12,A63,2
14FEB2017:11:59:14,T427,8
14FEB2017:11:59:14,T31212,8
14FEB2017:11:59:14,F900000,8
15FEB2017:03:55:23,K456,3 (because there are 3 cases happened on the same day)
15FEB2017:03:55:23,G578,3
15FEB2017:03:55:23,T213,3        
14FEB2017:05:56:12,F891,8
14FEB2017:05:56:12,A63,8
```

**My idea is:**

> 1. Take the values for the column Timestamp
> 2. Check if the date is the same,
> 3. Store all of the CaseID separated by space into a list based on the date,
> 4. Count the number of element in the list for each date then
> 5. Return the values for the counted elements into `Active-Tickets`.

But the problem here is, the amount of data is not small, assuming that there are 50 cases minimum in a day, then I don't think my way is possible.

Comment: I would use a hash indexed by the date field where the value would be a hash indexed by the CaseID having the number as value. It should be damned simple to implement using defaultdict, provided it can fit in memory. If you data is really huge, you could have a look at `shelve` or `sqlite3` modules. But this question is currently rather broad...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks. I will look at these modules. The data is around 2gb per file, so I can only test the sample which contains like thousands of them. When you're saying about sqlite3 modules, does this mean that I need to create a database for the csv file?

Comment: It depends on whether the input file is sorted by date/timestamp. If it is, you just have to keep on single day in memory so just forget about shelve or sqlite3. If order is plain random you can either first use an external sort program to fallback to first use case, or directly store on disk with a database, so yes you could store the relevant part of the csv file into a sqlites3 database and use a query with `GROUP BY dat, caseid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that using `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`. It only keeps the counts in memory, so might work in your case.  It reads the `csv` file in twice.  Once to get the counts, and once to write the output, but does the reads using iterators only, so should keep the memory needs down.

**Code:**

```
import csv
import itertools as it
from collections import Counter

# read through file and get counts per date
with open('test.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    dates = it.chain.from_iterable(
        [date for _ in ids.split()]
        for date, ids in ((x[0].split(':')[0], x[1]) for x in reader))
    counts = Counter(dates)

# read through file again, and output as individual records with counts
with open('test.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    records = it.chain.from_iterable(
        [(l[0], d) for d in l[1].split()] for l in reader)
    new_lines = (l + (str(counts[l[0].split(':')[0]]), ) for l in records)

    with open('test2.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
        writer = csv.writer(f_out)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerows(new_lines)
```

**Results:**

```
Timestamp,CaseID,Active-Tickets
14FEB2017:10:55:23,K456,8
14FEB2017:10:55:23,G578,8
14FEB2017:10:55:23,T213,8
13FEB2017:10:56:12,F891,2
13FEB2017:10:56:12,A63,2
14FEB2017:11:59:14,T427,8
14FEB2017:11:59:14,T31212,8
14FEB2017:11:59:14,F900000,8
15FEB2017:03:55:23,K456,3
15FEB2017:03:55:23,G578,3
15FEB2017:03:55:23,T213,3
14FEB2017:05:56:12,F891,8
14FEB2017:05:56:12,A63,8
```

**Counter in 2.6**

`collections.Counter` has been back ported for python 2.5+ ([Here](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class))

Comment: Hi , I got the following error. `_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte`. Does this mean that my CaseID cannot contains 0 data? So, I should remove the rows which contain empty data in CaseID column first and output a new csv file with non-NULL data in CaseID before running this code? or it's not what troubled me?